# Get element attributes and JSON from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

How can I make this work:

```html
<span data-instagram="https://www.instagram.com/p/BNnmcIVgNLy/?taken-by=nba"></span>
<span data-instagram="https://www.instagram.com/p/BNlZYpDgwr_/?taken-by=nba"></span>
<span data-instagram="https://www.instagram.com/p/BNlTnGFAqQ4/?taken-by=nba"></span>
<span data-instagram="https://www.instagram.com/p/BNlFOilgZ3b/?taken-by=nba"></span>
```

How can I search all span elements with atribute: data-instagram, and use it to extract instagram image thumbnail_url, and apend all images found to some div.

Something like this:

```js
$.getJSON ({
    method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/BNijakrAX5y/?taken-by=nba',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function (response) {
    $('.nekiDiv').append('<img src="'+response.thumbnail_url+'">');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nekiDiv">

</div>
```

You can also see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/ag53dm61/

Comment: If you know the url and you can keep it in html why not use a img tag and give url in `src` ?

Comment: I would like to do this way, but if that could work it would be fine too, but problem is i am not good with js and dont know how to manage it

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question body (rather than relying on a ilnk to an external site). Anyway, to get you started, `$("span[data-instagram]").each(function() { var url = $(this).attr("data-instagram"); /* ... */ });`

Answer (score 1):

*(I see why you can't use an `img` now: you don't have links to the actual thumbnails yet; you have to go through the Instagram API to get them first.)*

You can use jQuery to select every `span` with a `data-instagram` attribute:

```
$('span[data-instagram]')
```

Then, for each element that was found, you can mimic the functionality in the fiddle you linked to query the Instagram API. When the request succeeds, you can then use the callback function to insert the respective thumbnail image into each `span`.

**Take a look at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgpnynnw/).**

(StackOverflow snippets seem to be having trouble initiating cross-origin requests.)

```js
$('span[data-instagram]').each(function(i, span) {
  $.getJSON({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=' + span.getAttribute('data-instagram'),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response) {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = response.thumbnail_url;
      span.appendChild(img)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
  <span data-instagram="https://www.instagram.com/p/BNnmcIVgNLy/?taken-by=nba"></span>
  <span data-instagram="https://www.instagram.com/p/BNlZYpDgwr_/?taken-by=nba"></span>
  <span data-instagram="https://www.instagram.com/p/BNlTnGFAqQ4/?taken-by=nba"></span>
  <span data-instagram="https://www.instagram.com/p/BNlFOilgZ3b/?taken-by=nba"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, just one more little tweak i need. In html i dont have `<div class="images"></div>`(i have only few span elements i mentioned in my question), so when the request succeeds,  i want to create that `<div class="images"></div>` and insert all the respective thumbnail images not into each span, but into `<div class="images"></div>` wich will be created when the request succeeds. At the end it should look like: `<div class="images"><img src="1" /><img src="2" /><img src="3" /><img src="4" /> ... </div>`  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't use direct url's, you need to use [instagram api](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) url,

Then you can use js code as:

```
$("[data-instagram]").each(function(el) {
  $.getJSON({
    method: 'GET',
    url: $(this).data("instagram"),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response) {
      $('.nekiDiv').append('<img src="' + response.thumbnail_url + '">');
    }
  });
})
```

Example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v6kduy8e/)

You need to create a div with `nekiDiv` in HTML.

And see the first example url as `"https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/BNijakrAX5y/?taken-by=nba"`